# ASP.NET: Serve large video as content with one time url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need serve a very large video (1gb) as content and in order to do it I using the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ///check the token

    ///proceed if token if valid
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
    var wc = new WebClient();

    string filePath = Server.MapPath("videos/vid.mp4");

    //Context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

    const int chunkSize = 1024; // read the file by chunks of 1KB
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }

    Response.End();
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is this the right way?
2. Video is getting played but video's seek bar is not working.
3. How to provide video in chunks to the client?

Comment: Is there a resaon why you don't let IIS serve the file instead? But, IMHO, videos of such size should be served via a CDN. A CDN supports http pseudo streaming by default and you wont stress your web server.

Comment: Reasone is one time url and the video will be played only once

Comment: I have worked with Amazon's CDN CloudFront, and using that, you can create signed URLs where you can control how long they will be valid and perform authentication, see here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html. I am confident that other CDN vendors will provide similar functionality.

Comment: I am using godaddy hosting server for asp.net. i hope you understand that not all can afford AWS or GAE :) also small project cannot afford dedicated vms

Comment: Of course I understand that, but serving 1GB video files through the ASP.NET engine can very quickly hog your website down. But let's go back on topic. If you let IIS serve the file, the video seek bar is working?

Comment: Yes the seek bar is working fine if i am directly serving it from iis or localhost

Comment: Take a look here http://www.primaryobjects.com/2009/11/11/securing-pdf-files-in-asp-net-with-custom-http-handlers/. You can have a custom HTTP handler that will decide whether your user has access to the file or not. This way, you can let IIS server the file. The handler runs on every request made, so you have full control over it.

Comment: Thank-you and i will go through it. Many thanks @TasosK